# Client-server messaging protocol for online interactions

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, client-server, protocols

I have a web application in which a number of people send and receive messages via a server. This kind of interaction lasts for a number of periods.

In each period, there is a common pattern: clients send messages to the server and expect a response from it; Once receiving the response, the clients proceed to the next period. However, the server only respond when it receives messages from all the clients/people involved in the interaction.

A problem rises when someone's message fails to reach the server, resulting a situation where the server is waiting for the message from this client/person - and the interaction simply hangs. This possibility is real as the interaction happens over the Internet.

I understand that if the problem is caused by a power-cut or a computer crash at the client-side, then there is nothing I can do. However, in case that the message is lost due to traffic/load in transmission or temporary client-side application problems which prevent the sending of the message (e.g. browser freezes or OS stops responding for a couple of seconds), I wonder if there is anything I can do to fix the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Reliable Message Delivery](http://www.soapatterns.org/reliable_messaging.php) and there are several approaches, for a simple web application you could use a two part acknowledgement; acknowledge receipt and then progress.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Could you please elaborate this scheme a bit, the description in the link offers only a vague overview. Some concrete example will be immensely helpful.